# Check for UWP Desktop extensions presence

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I added the following line:

```
FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher)

but I want to be able to check whether this will work (preferably without a try-catch block). Is there some way to test whether desktop extensions are present?

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to do this is:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
{
   await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation for the version numbers? I don't mean for `IsApiContractPresent`, or for the `API contract` (which thanks to your answer, I found on the former's page.) I mean for the version numbers. The version number for the desktop extensions is of the format `10.0.the rest`. so it would seem to mean that we need to test for **10**.0, not **1**.0.

Comment: You test for the version number of the contract, not the version of the OS. The version number of the contract is documented in the API reference topic on MSDN, e.g. here for FullTrustProcessLauncher.* APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher

Comment: It doesn't mention the version. It just says that it was _introduced_ in v1. But what version am I using? There are 4 versions of the desktop extension, all beginning with 10.0. And even if the 2 aren't related, who said that the version _I'm_ using is 1?

Comment: Two different things: contract version and SDK version. To dynamically light up this feature on devices and OS versions that support this extension check the contract version as shown in my answer. If you don't want your app to be available on earlier versions of Windows 10 before this feature was introduced, set the minversion of your app to the SDK version this API was introduced in. This version info is also listed on the MSDN page (it's 14393 for this one).

Comment: But why did you write `1` for the version? Where did that come from?

Comment: (Another question which you may be able to help me with: [The debugger was unable to find the registration for the target application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352103/the-debugger-was-unable-to-find-the-registration-for-the-target-application) )

Comment: The '1' is taken from the MSDN documentation, which specifies that the LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync() method is included in v1 of the FullTrustAppContract. Imagine in the next release we'll add a new method to that contract then that method would only be available in v2 of the contract, and you would check for '2' if you want to light up that API. Makes sense?

Comment: Only if v2 will return `true` if we check for v1. Are you saying it will/does? (Kind of like saying that testing for .net 3.5 on a computer running .net 4.7 only will return true. Which, as far as I know is _not_ true.)

Comment: Yes, it will return true if you run on a machine that has v2 of the API contract. Learn more about it from this blog post: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/#F1rKTVzYlElt2opF.97

Comment: (RE: Checking for .NET Versions) In **general**, you should not assume that version X of something implies anything about versions < X or > X. Nevertheless, in the specific instance of **API Contracts** they are defined such that version X always has the features of versions < X. So it's safe to assume that v2 implies v1, but only for API Contracts.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks. If you have an official source for that that would be helpful. I've seen similar thing about .net standard, but never about this.