# "The debugger was unable to find the registration for the target application."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a UWP app (from a Xamarin.Forms app) which debugs fine on the computer. But when I try to debug on a phone, I get the following error:

> Unable to debug Windows Store app '....exe'. The debugger was unable
>   to find the registration for the target application. If the problem
>   persists, try uninstalling and then reinstalling this application.

The app does get installed on the phone and can be executed there. But I can't debug it with Visual Studio.

Meanwhile, the error I see in the error list in VS is:

> DEP6700: LaunchMsvsmon failed on the device side. [0x800401F3] Invalid
>   class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))

I uninstalled both on the computer and on the phone, I rebooted both, I deleted the .vs folder, bin and obj folders... Nothing helped.

What are these errors telling me?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the **Maximum SDK** version supported by windows phone is Windows 10 Creators Update (Build 15063). If your project target version is  **Fall Creators Update (Build 16299)**, it will not be supported.

If your **Shared** project is `Portable Class Library`, you could modify the target version to Windows 10 Creators Update (Build 15063).

However, if you have used `.NET Standard` shared project, and it only support Fall Creators Update (Build 16299). You could not modify the target version.

Comment: I'm using PCL and I now changed the target version  to 15063 (the minimum version has been under that already). It still gives me the same error despite deleting the `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folders, and uninstalling the app from the phone.

Comment: What is the OS version of the phone? And have you tried to deploy app in your desktop

Comment: It works on desktop with Visual Studio and on the phone only separately - not from within VS. The OS on the phone is 10.0.15254.158. It's a Lumia 550.

Comment: Try to clean solution or delete `bin` `obj` folder .

Comment: I already deleted them as I've stated in my first comment. I've also deleted `.vs` and closed VS and reopened...

Comment: I don't think so. Because this app used to work. Then I changed the minimum version to 16299, (and obviously it couldn't even deploy to mobile), and then I changed back and it's not working even after deleting the folders, and the nuget packages, and restarting,...

Comment: Did you mean that  the issue occurred after changing the minimum version to 16299?

Comment: After changing the minimum version to 16299 I couldn't (of course) deploy to the phone. _The_ issue, though, is that even after returning to min of anniversary update, and now after your answer, to target of 15063 it gives me this error.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy  a blank app that target version is 15063?